# Dynamic Rendering Of React Components Based On External Data

Tags: reactjs, react-router, rendering, react-component

I want your help,  I wanna a method to render pages components with routing but i want a method to do that using an external array (like routes here) and map() method not to hardcoded every route.

````
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

 const routes = [
    {
      name: 'home',
      path: '/',
      componentName: 'Home'
    },
    {
      name: 'about',
      path: '/about',
      componentName: 'About'
    },
    {
      name: 'contact',
      path: '/contact',
      componentName: 'Contact'
    }
]
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
    const nav = this.routes.map((route, i) => 
    <route key={i} path={route.path} element={<{`${route.componentName}`} /* Here is the issue I know this isn't work but i want a method to do the same thing */ /> }/>
)

return (
  <Router>
    <div className='App'> 
      <Routes>{nav}</Routes>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
  } 
}```
````

Comment: how would you decide which component to load for which route ?

Answer (score 0):

please Change `<route key={i} path={route.path} />` to `<Route key={i} path={route.path} />` maybe typo mistake `Route`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't fill the tag in with a string, it needs to be an actual React component reference. You need to import the components you want to render on the routes.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import About from '../pages/About';
import Contact from '../pages/Contact';

const routes = [
  {
    name: 'home',
    path: '/',
    Component: Home // <-- reference imported component
  },
  {
    name: 'about',
    path: '/about',
    Component: About
  },
  {
    name: 'contact',
    path: '/contact',
    Component: Contact
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const nav = routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
      <Route // <-- render Route component
        key={path}
        path={path}
        element={<Component /> } // <-- pass Component to element as JSX
      />
    ));

    return (
      <Router>
        <div className='App'> 
          <Routes>{nav}</Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  } 
}
```

Also, `react-router-dom@6` effectively has a React hook to do exactly this. If you are open to using React function components then I suggest using the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-routes) hook instead.

> The `useRoutes` hook is the functional equivalent of [`<Routes>`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/routes), but it
> uses JavaScript objects instead of `<Route>` elements to define your
> routes. These objects have the same properties as normal [`<Route>`
> elements](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route), but they don't require JSX.
>
> The return value of `useRoutes` is either a valid React element you can
> use to render the route tree, or `null` if nothing matched.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import About from '../pages/About';
import Contact from '../pages/Contact';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    element: <About />
  },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    element: <Contact />
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {appRoutes}
    </div>
  ); 
}
```

Wrap the `App` component in the `Router` so `App` can use the `useRoutes` hook.

```
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I search!! Thank a lot man.